# Animate icon in Actionbar jumping and become larger

Tags: android, menu, jquery-animate

I am using an icon in Actionbar for refreshing, after clicking the refresh button it is circulating well, but it is jumping and become much larger than menu icon.

Menu and refresh icon:

[image: menu and refresh icon]

Menu status after clicking:

[image: menu status after clicking]

codes are as follow:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Our created menu to use
    private Menu mymenu;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_people);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // We should save our menu so we can use it to reset our updater.
        mymenu = menu;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                // Do animation start





                //TODO trigger loading


                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.iv_refresh,null);
                Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_refresh);
                rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

                iv.startAnimation(rotation);

                item.setActionView(iv);

                new UpdateTask(this).execute();
                return true;
            case R.id.home:
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
    public void resetUpdating()
    {
        // Get our refresh item from the menu
        MenuItem m = mymenu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
        if(m.getActionView()!=null)
        {
            // Remove the animation.
            m.getActionView().clearAnimation();
            m.setActionView(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**iv_refresh.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ImageView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="-40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="-40dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/refresh" />
```

**rotate_refresh.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360"/>
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.google.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/refresh"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do the following:

1- add the xml attribute for the menu item

```
android:actionLayout="@layout/iv_refresh"
```

to be

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Refresh"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/iv_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/refresh"/>
```

2- upon selecting the item in `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
    case R.id.action_refresh:
       ImageView iv = (ImageView) item.getActionView();

    Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  R.anim.rotate_refresh);
    rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

    iv.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but it is not applicable to set two times the imageView.  ImageView iv = (ImageView)inflater...

Comment: item.setActionView(iv);

Comment: what I meant don't inflate programatically .I edited my answer